# C : mmap initialize at 0xffffffff

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, mmap

I am currently doing a memory allocator for a C project and I am facing something that I don't understand

I'm calling mmap to reserve the heap for my program where i will put some headers.

I have

```
void * START_ADDRESS;
int MEMORY_INITIALIZED;

void* Mem_Init(int sizeOfRegion){
    START_ADDRESS = mmap(NULL, sizeOfRegion, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FILE |MAP_PRIVATE, -1,0);

    header_t* startingHeader = START_ADDRESS;

    //rest of the fontion
}

void* Mem_Alloc(int size){
    if(MEMORY_INITIALIZED==0){
    START_ADDRESS= Mem_Init(size); 

    //rest of the funtion
}
```

When i use the errno on this code it returns me the invalid Argument error.

Why do mmap returns a valid adress when i call it using the Mem_Init method and why do it returns me invalidArgument when i call Mem_Init in the Mem_Alloc method ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is not valid C. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: `0xffffffff` is probably `MAP_FAILED`, which means it got an error. `errno` will contain the reason.

Comment: What is `-1 0` at the end of the `MMAP` call? There should be a comma between the parameters.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have both `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and `MAP_FILE`.

Comment: What is the `MMAP` function? The standard function is `mmap`, lowercase.

Comment: Copy-paste errors ? Please edit !

Comment: Camel case is bad enough, but all-caps variable names?  Gah!  Have a scrap of decency, man!

Comment: it is CAPS variable because it is global variables, i just don't put my whole code ;)

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Please post an MCVE as requested. For example, "when I call Mem_Init it returns me an adress like 0xbcfd210 which is something ok, but when I call it while in the Mem_Alloc method mmap returns me 0xffffffff". That doesn't really make sense. The only place that calls `mmap` shown is `Mem_Init`. So what do you mean exactly by some calls fail and some calls don't? Show those exact calls in your code.

Comment: I edited my question, i added the errno returned by the mmap and a make some cleanup in the text

Comment: You told `mmap` to use a file `MAP_FILE` but then didn't give it a valid open file descriptor. So it's the `-1` for the file descriptor that it's complaining about.

Comment: "Why do mmap returns a valid adress when i call it using the Mem_Init method and why do it returns me invalidArgument when i call Mem_Init in the Mem_Alloc method?" -- presumably because in the latter case you pass `mmap()` an invalid argument.  That suggests that you pass a *different* argument when you call `Mem_Init()` directly than when you call `Mem_Alloc`.  Alternatively, perhaps the parts you left out contain the actual problem code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger even if I remove the MAP_FILE it still don't work

Comment: @user3386109, the arguments are certainly suspicious, but note that he also passes `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, which conflicts with `MAP_FILE` and which in some implementations *requires* `-1` to be passed as the file descriptor.

Comment: Yes, i also tried by removing the MAP_FILE arguments but i still have the same problem, maybe it is a problem due to the fact I am using a Virtual Machine.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was just trying to see if I could get OP to acknowledge and act upon Barmar's third comment. Mission accomplished. Now the objective is to get OP to acknowledge and act upon ColonelThirtyTwo's first comment. I expect that the question will be closed before that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the error.

In the test program the teacher gave us, he tried to allocate a 0 size header, and mmap fails when you try to alocate a null pointer.

A simple correction was

```
void* Mem_Init(int sizeOfRegion){
    if(sizeOfRegion==0) sizeOfRegion = 1024; //1024 is an exemple
    START_ADDRESS = mmap(NULL, sizeOfRegion, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FILE |MAP_PRIVATE, -1,0);

    if ((void *) -1 == START_ADDRESS) {
        printf("Could not map memory: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
```

Thanks for the support guys

Comment: I don't think that is right. From the man page: `If addr is NULL, then the kernel chooses the address at which to create the mapping; this is the most portable method of creating a new mapping.`

Comment: Yes, i have checked and I agree with your point of view. But as we ask for a region which have a NULL size, i think the kernel init a map of size 0 at a valid place and in order to have the least conflicts possible it initialize it at the end of the memory. This is my point of view, but maybe it works diffrently....

Answer (score 2):

With some minor changes, your code appears to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

void * START_ADDRESS;
int MEMORY_INITIALIZED = 0;

void* Mem_Init(int sizeOfRegion){
    START_ADDRESS = mmap(NULL, sizeOfRegion, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FILE |MAP_PRIVATE, -1,0);

    if ((void *) -1 == START_ADDRESS) {
        printf("Could not map memory: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    printf("%p\n", START_ADDRESS);

    void* startingHeader = START_ADDRESS;

    //rest of the fontion
    return startingHeader;
}

void* Mem_Alloc(int size){
    if(MEMORY_INITIALIZED==0){
    START_ADDRESS= Mem_Init(size); 
    }

    //rest of the funtion
    return START_ADDRESS;
}

int main(void) {
    Mem_Alloc(1024);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -o code code.c
```

I thought the most important change is that MEMORY_INITIALIZED is set to 0, but the language lawyers assure me that this is already done by compilers that follow the C89 standard.

Comment: Global variables are automatically initialised to 0 already. That can't be the problem.

Comment: Maybe it comes from the fact that OP is using a Virtual Machine ? (see previous comments)
Besides, I think OP does not want to use *mmap* more than once, so only Mem_Alloc should be called in the main. That's what the problem was about at start, calling *mmap* from Mem_Alloc or directly from Mem_Init

Comment: I meant to call Mem_Alloc in main. After the change, the code still works. The code was compiled and run on a Virtual Machine.